# automating csv download from mysql database

Tags: mysql, powerbi, reporting

I have about 12 separate queries that produce different data that is used to generate reports, mainly using PowerBI

I have tried connecting power bi to MySQL database but it takes a long time and I might as well just download the CSV file and use it in power bi

so far I've tried

- downloading the data using MySQL workbench and using the csv files to generate the reports using power bi, but this means I have to run 12 separate queries to finish each
- connecting excel to MySQL and running the query but this also takes a long time

I figured using anything aside from MySQL workbench would take longer,

is there a way to automate the queries and download the CSV result (not "into file" as this doesn't provide the downloadable file

thank you